# Is it possible to simulate browser click events?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, mouseevent

How can I simulate exact behave of mouse click on a browser's button (e.g. Firefox)?
When user clicks on a button using mouse click then an event is generated. Could I use or call the event manually?

I can use Javascript to simulate click on a button but it will not call the same event in the same way as when a user really clicks on the button.

The reason I ask for solution: record engine for recording any event occur in the document level works in background, I want to create web app with self play functionality, that means when I browse the web app in browser it will do business flow automatically and then the engine will record the events.

Please ask if my question not clear, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest with something like jQuery.

```
//listen for clicks - real or simulated
$('#some_element').on('click', function() { alert('click!'); });

//simulate clicks (two ways)
$('#some_element').click();
$('#some_element').trigger('click');
```

It is possible to know, from inside the event callback, whether the event was real or simulated. I did a [blog post on this](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Apr/Distinguishing-real-events-from-simulated-events-209) some months ago.

Comment: the jQuery example will create not original event and in this case I will not be able to catch the event, in your blog post I found that you can determine if the event is original or not, but how could I create original event?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).  It uses automation and other native APIs to simulate user input in exactly the way you wish.

Comment: If we are talking about record DOM objects and user action then will be good option to use LR TruClient new protocol, I want to know how to emulate call event!!